# Optional compile of Google Play Services in an Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am developing an app that requires Google Play Services to show Google Maps. However, I need to create APK file that could also be installed on devices that doesn't support Google Play Services (the maps wouldn't be shown on these devices).

Is there any option to create some compile variables or something else that could make such development process easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gradle Build Variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) are designed exactly for these types of things, allowing you to have a common code base, but change certain behaviors and make building multiple APKs much easier. It also handles things like Manifest merging which allows you to only include features in certain APKs.

Of course, it requires that you switch to Gradle and hence, [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)), so there's definitely some learning curve involved.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  In fact doing so would be a copyright violation.  OEMs need to pay Google and follow certain rules to be allowed to use Google Play Services.

Comment: So what are my options if I need to create 2 versions of the APK every time (i.e. one without Google Maps support)?

Comment: You can do 1 apk-  check if google maps exists on the device, and if not turn off the parts of your app/ui that require it.

Comment: I cannot install APK with Google Maps enabled when I have some references to G. Play Services in my `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: @REACHUS you must check if the device has google play services at runtime, if not then dont give the user the option to go to that part of your app

Comment: The problem is I get `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` error when I install the app.